# Deploy Flexipage Assignment

Tags: deployment, flexipages

I created a pull request that encompasses the creation of a new flexipage, as well as assigning this new flexipage as the org-default. It is also supposed to remove all redundant App-Profile-RecordType manual assignments (via deletion of  in the CustomApplication-file).

After the build finished the flexipage made it to the target-org, however, the assignments did not. Does anybody have an idea why this could have happened?

I feel like I will need a post-deployment step, which I would like to avoid.

Answer (score 4):

Flexipage assignment on org default level can be deployed with [ActionOverride](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/actionoverride.htm) metadata. It is a nested metadata inside CustomObject metadata type.

From the documentation:

> To set a Lightning page action override on the View standard button in
> Lightning Experience, use:
>
> ```
> <CustomObject xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
>     <actionOverrides>
>         <actionName>View</actionName>
>         <content>myLightningPage</content>
>         <formFactor>Large</formFactor>
>         <type>flexipage</type>
>     </actionOverrides>
> </CustomObject>
> ```

Comment: does that work for Knowledge object?